# Why when making a loop it's all the time reset to 0 on next iterations?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method with some loops inside:

```
private void RefreshListBox()
        {
            int i = 0, j = 0, index, count;
            Boolean bl = false;

            index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            count = windowsHandles.Count;

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (!Constants.IsWindow(windowsHandles[j]))
                {
                    windowsHandles.RemoveAt(j);
                    windowsText.RemoveAt(j);
                    windowsBitmaps.RemoveAt(j);
                    rectanglesList.RemoveAt(j);
                    isCroppedList.RemoveAt(j);
                    canDrawNormallyList.RemoveAt(j);

                    if (j < index)
                    {
                        index--;
                    }
                    else if (j == index)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }
                else { j++; }
            }

            if (index == windowsHandles.Count)
            {
                index--;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < windows.Count; x++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < windowsHandles.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (windowsHandles[j] == windows[x].Handle) { bl = true; break; }
                }

                        if (bl == false && Constants.IsIconic(windows[x].Handle))
                        {
                            windowsHandles.Add(windows[x].Handle);
                            windowsText.Add(windows[x].Title);
                            windowsBitmaps.Add(null);
                            rectanglesList.Add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
                            isCroppedList.Add(false);
                            canDrawNormallyList.Add(false);
                        }

                    bl = false;
            }

            if (windowsHandles.Count > 0 && index == -1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }


            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0) { listBox1.Items.Clear(); }

            for (i = 0; i < windowsHandles.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(windowsText[i]);
            }

            if (index != -1)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
            }

            textBoxIndex.Text = windowsHandles.Count.ToString();
            drawPicBox(index);
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                var item = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
                if (item >= 0)
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = item;

                    drawPicBox(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem start when it's getting to the loop at this line:

```
for (int x = 0; x < windows.Count; x++)
```

The Count of windows List is 21 in this case.
Then it's entering first time but if i put a break point on this line and click continue all the time i see that x is 0.

When i put a break point on this line:

```
windowsHandles.Add(windows[x].Handle);
```

It stop there each time i click on continue but then i see that the variable x it's value is 20 all the time. And the List windowsHandles contain only 1 item.

Then i put a break point on the line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(windowsText[i]);
```

And when i  make continue it stop on the line but even if it does the line there are no items on the listBox1.

If i don't use any break points and just make continue to let it run it's never show/get to the form it's like stuck somewhere in this method can't figure out where and why.

In the constructor i'm calling two methods.
First GetWindows then RefreshList

```
GetWindows();
RefreshListBox();
```

In GetWindows:

```
private List<Window> windows = new List<Window>();

        private void GetWindows()
        {
            windows = new List<Window>();
            Constants.EnumWindows(Callback, 0);
        }


        private bool Callback(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.Handle != hwnd && (Constants.GetWindowLongA(hwnd, Constants.GWL_STYLE) & Constants.TARGETWINDOW) == Constants.TARGETWINDOW)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
                    Constants.GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

                    Window t = new Window();
                    t.Handle = hwnd;
                    t.Title = sb.ToString();
                    windows.Add(t);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"e:\errors.txt");
                w.Write(err.ToString());
                w.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

In the end of the GetWindows operation i see that windows contain 21 items.
The problem seems to be somewhere in the RefreshList method but i can't figure out where is the problem.

The goal of all this in the end is to add all the items in windowsText to the listBox1.

Comment: You should scrap iterating by index, you run the risk of index out of bounds issues due to the collection changing. Instead cast the items .ToList() (even though its already a list, this will create a copy) then use a foreach iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed something else:

```
windowsHandles.Add(windows[x].Handle);
windowsText.Add(windows[x].Title);
windowsBitmaps.Add(null); // <------
rectanglesList.Add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
isCroppedList.Add(false);
canDrawNormallyList.Add(false);
```

Is this a correct guess - The reason you're adding a `null` to `windowsBitmaps` is so that all six of these collections stay in sync. The items across each collection are related somehow if they have the same index.

It would be much easier if you created one class with properties for `windowsHandle`, `windowsText`, `windowsBitmaps`, etc, and then had a collection of that type. That way instead of managing six collections and trying to keep them in sync you only have one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but I think it's a necessary step if you're going to get to the answer: break this up into smaller methods.

You could start with the loops. You could put each of those loops in a separate method and name the method very clearly so that it indicates what it's doing and what it's doing it to. (It might even be worthwhile to put some of the functions in separate classes.)

One of the reasons is that no one - not you or the programmer who works on this later - can expect to be able to hold the complexity of one long method in their head and follow through 'what if this happens, what if that happens.'

Same thing for variable names. It's okay if variable names and method names are long if they help make it clear what they are for. I find myself seeing `x` and having to scroll back up to see what `x` is, and then I lose track of where I was.

I know that's not a direct answer. But if you do that then the answer will likely be easier to see. If you break it up into smaller functions (or even write separate classes) then you can also write unit tests. That way instead of running the whole thing from top to bottom you can just test one part at a time.

### More directly related

Somewhat more directly related to the code: If you do need to iterate through a collection and possibly remove items as you go, it's better to start from the `Count` and work backwards. That way your index stays in bounds.

An even easier way is to use Linq to query the elements and create a new collection. For example

```
Thing[] arrayOfSomething = GetAnArrayOfSomething();

var arrayWithElementsRemoved = arrayOfSomething.Where(
    item => !item.DeleteThisOne).ToArray();
```

The second statement takes an array of `Thing` and returns a new array containing only the ones where `DeleteThisOne` is `false`. It's all in one statement, no looping or bounds to worry about.